# MYSQL joining tables and selecting customer with no order for particular date

Tags: mysql, inner-join, notin

I am having trouble with this mysql query. I have a customer table and an orders table, linked by a customer ID. The orders table has a date field and I am trying to list the names of customers that do not have any orders for a particular month, July 2016. I was told a `NOT IN` might help but I'm not sure how to go about it. I looked for similar examples but they use `IS NULL`. I tried this but it did not like the `NOT` (not a valid input at this position:

`SELECT customer.cust_name
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN ordertbl ON ordertbl.cust_id = customer.cust_id
WHERE order_date like '2016-07%' not in ordertbl.order_date;`

I then tried this but it returned no results:

`SELECT customer.cust_name
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN ordertbl ON ordertbl.cust_id = customer.cust_id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(order_date like '2016-07%')) IS NULL;`

I also found a similar example but couldn't get it, no results:

`Select customer.cust_name
From customer
where ordertbl.cust_id Not in (
Select customer.cust_id
From ordertbl
Where ordertbl.order_date like '2016-07%');`

I'm sure I'm going about this all wrong. I tried a few other examples but those didn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Still truggling? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in the orders table, your customer ID reference is called CUSTOMER_ID, the query is:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUST_NAME
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUST_ID IN
        (SELECT ORDERTBL.CUSTOMER_ID 
        FROM ORDERTBL
        WHERE DATE <> yourdate)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked as intended but I have a question about the date. I don't want a specific date but a month so I was using `LIKE '2016-07' instead of `<> yourdate. It seems to have worked but based on the fact that you used `<>` I would have expected to have to use `NOT LIKE` instead. Can you explain why that is not the case?

Comment: To use LIKE operator, you should convert the date to text. But it's easier instaed, writing : 
WHERE DATE >= '2017-01-01' AND DATE <= '2017-01-02' for range.